# gnuplot Heatmap with label and score from different columns data

Tags: graph, gnuplot, heatmap

I have created heatmap graphs using gnuplot.
I have data.dat:

```
       avail    reli    perf    
stop    181 20  121 10  34 20
jitter  18 20   17 20   13 20
limp    12 20   5 30    20 20
```

and gnuplot script:

```
set term pos eps font 20
unset key
set nocbtics
set cblabel "Score" 
set cbtics scale 0
set cbrange [ 0.00000 : 110.00000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set palette defined ( 0.0 "#FFFFFF",\
                      1 "#FFCCCC",\
                      20.2 "#FF9999 ",\
                      30.3 "#FF6666",\
                      40.4 "#FF3333",\
                      50.5 "#FF0000",\
                      60.6 "#CC0000",\
                      70.7 "#C00000",\
                      80.8 "#B00000",\
                      90.9 "#990000",\
                      100.0 "#A00000")

set title "Faults"

set ylabel "Hardware Faults"
set xlabel "Aspects"
set size 1, 0.5
set output 'c11.eps'
YTICS="`awk 'BEGIN{getline}{printf "%s ",$1}' 'data2.dat'`"
XTICS="`head -1 'data2.dat'`"
set for [i=1:words(XTICS)] xtics ( word(XTICS,i) i-1 )
set for [i=1:words(YTICS)] ytics ( word(YTICS,i) i-1 )

plot "<awk '{$1=\"\"}1' 'data2.dat' | sed '1 d'" matrix w image, '' matrix using 1:2:($3==0 ? " " : sprintf("%.1d",$3)) with labels
#######^ replace the first field with nothing
################################## ^ delete first line
```

My output is:

[image]

Here I have range 1-20,30-39,...,100 or more)
Now I have to 2 values in every axis. e.g stop and avail have(181 and 20). the 181 is the count and 20 is percentages. I want to create graphs which have colors base on percentages and the labels on my graphs from the counts of data.

I have experienced create some graph using for and do some modulo to select the data. But here, I have not idea to create that graphs. Any suggestion for creating this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `every` to skip columns.

`plot ... every 2` only uses every second column, which is what you can use for the labels. For the colors, you must start with the second column (numbered with `1`), and you need `every 2::1`.

Following are the relevant changes only to your script:

```
set for [i=1:words(XTICS)] xtics ( word(XTICS,i) 2*i-1 )
plot "<awk '{$1=\"\"}1' 'data2.dat' | sed '1 d'" matrix every 2::1 w image, \
     '' matrix using ($1+1):2:(sprintf('%d', $3)) every 2 with labels
```

The result with 4.6.5 is:

[image]